# Execute batch job (JSR 352) on startup

Tags: glassfish-4, java-ee-7

I have a batchjob and need to run it up the application. He makes the call for the job, but the job does not reach the method.

`BatchRuntime.getJobOperator().start(JOB_NAME, new Properties());`

Throws no errors. So it seems that he is looking for the resource that indicates which class Implementing this job, but not yet loaded. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

The start() method is asynch so the caller isn't going to always see exceptions on failure.

Is the XML corresponding to JOB_NAME found?    Any errors in the logs?

Comment: When I call the start () method. I keep the id and take the job status. Always stays in STARTING. No error in the log.

Comment: It sounds like the execution via the ExecutorService might not be working smoothly.  I saw you tagged this as a Glassfish env.  Could your thread pool be exhausted or somehow not configured correctly?